# Pandas aggregation for column with hours

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame where a column contains information for **some of** the hours of each day week:

```
 Day     Hour   HeartRate
Monday    7        65      
Monday    8        66
Monday    9        66
Tuesday   7        68
Tuesday   9        68
Tuesday   10       58
```

How can I groupby this dataframe on day and get a column of HeartRate for each hour, while filling with zeros the hours where I do not have a heart rate (assuming a 24h day)?

Example output:

```
Day.        HeartRate
Monday.     [0,0,0,0,0,0,65,66,66,0, ... ,0  
Tuesday     [0,0,0,0,0,0,65,0,66,58, ... ,0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `pivot` + `reindex`

```
out = df.pivot(*df.columns).reindex(columns=range(23)).fillna(0).astype(int).agg(list,1)
Day
Monday     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 65, 66, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
Tuesday    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 68, 0, 68, 58, 0, 0, 0, ...
dtype: object

out = out.to_frame('HeartRate').reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. What would change if I have another column where I want to aggregate it at the same time using, for example, the sum of it? My question boils down basically on how to combine this aggregation if I have extra columns where I want to apply typical agg statements.\